# i need to set 10 random expression using random operation

Tags: java, android

what i m trying to do is set 10 questions with random expression with randon operators +-/*. but the problem tht i m getting is that the random expressions never stops when # is pressed

code is

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
        
        
        
        switch(arg0.getId()){   
        case R.id.keypad_hash:
                    
            fnum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10))); 
            snum0 = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10))); 
            String str = ""; 
            int operation = (int) ((double) ((Math.random() * 10))); 
             
        
            if(operation == 0)  
               str = fnum0 + "+" + snum0; 
            else if(operation == 1) 
               str = fnum0 + "-" + snum0; 
            else if(operation == 2)  
               str = fnum0 + "*" + snum0; 
            else  
               str = fnum0 + "/" + snum0; 
             
            display.setText(str); 

            
      

             
        }   
     });
```

Comment: where is the code that deals with the '#' character?

Comment: @Wizetux, right there.  See `R.id.keypad_hash` ?  I asked the same question, though.

Comment: what are you expecting? arg0 (a View).getId() wont be returning the char typed will it?

Comment: @ahmed, "the random expressions never stops" is completely unclear.  Try to ask your question in the form of a question.  Present both what is actually happening and what you expect to happen.  If there are any errors, state them, or include the logcat.  Don't speak as if you're expecting a long back-and-forth before your question can be answered.

Comment: @JulianFondren: Oh he meant the View object called Hash rather than the ascii character '#'.  That is rather confusing.

Comment: @Julian, the random question are keeping of generating as many time key_hash is pressed however i want it to stop as soon as random expressions reaches 10 questions when keypad_hash is pressed 10 times

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you've cut out other cases below the `R.id.keypad_hash`, and that the problem you're observing is that the behavior of the next case is seen after the behavior of this one, (and also that the next case is coded in such a way that you *can* observe both behaviors), as you neither `break` from the switch nor `return` from onClick.  Please learn about [switches in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html).

Short answer: add a `break;`, as in

```
switch(arg0.getId()){
  case R.id.keypad_hash:
    fnum0 = ...

    display.setText(str);
    break;
  case ...:
    ...
  default:
    ...
}
```

And please also indicate when you remove code, as with the ellipses (...) above.  Your code, *as presented,* doesn't need a `break`.

Comment: i tried that but it still not work, BASICALLY what i m trying to do is each time when i pressed keypad_hash it generates a random expression with a random genarator and do this until 10 questions are complete.. but at the moment it keep on generating the expression even if the 10 question are done.

Comment: @ahmed, ... OK.  You want that button to be non-functional after it's been pressed ten times? Then count the number of presses, and do nothing after the tenth.  Or disable the button after the tenth.

Comment: @julian.. disable the button after the tenth